# Connection error for RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am completely new to MQs and pika.

When I am trying to execute this code(server code) I am getting errors:
(I am getting same error for receiver code also.)

```
import pika
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
     host="localhost:5672"))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                  routing_key='hello',
                  body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Workspace\Luna_WS\MQ\RabbitMQ\Sample\Src\Sample.py", line 10, in <module>
host="localhost:5672"))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 339, in __init__
self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
self._open_error_result.is_ready)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 395, in _flush_output
raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

I had installed: (using windows 7, 32 bit)

pikka package - pika-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Erlang - esl-erlang_18.2-1-windows_i386

RabbitMq server - rabbitmq-server-3.6.0

Comment: I have set environment variables RABBITMQ_SERVER to C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.0 and RABBITMQ_BASE to C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server

Comment: are there any more environment variable to be set to make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try splitting the host into separate host and port connection parameters:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
                 pika.ConnectionParameters(host="localhost", port=5672))
```

Comment: no, its not working same error with  host="localhost",port=5672))

Comment: @NagaumadeviPalaparthy: oh well, worth a shot. It is documented with the separate parameters so you should probably retain that invocation.

Comment: @NagaumadeviPalaparthy: Are you sure that your rabbitmq-server is using host `localhost` and port `5672`? If not you will see the same error as you show. And, actually, it works for me using `host="localhost", port=5672` but  `host="localhost:5672"` fails as per your traceback. So both `host` and `port` parameters are required. You need to double check your server.

Comment: how can i check my server

Comment: First check that the server is actually running using task manager or similar. Next try looking in the server logs for a line like this `started TCP Listener on [::]:5672`. If you installed the server without modifying the configuration it should be listening on port 5672, but it's also worth looking at the `rabbitmq.config` configuration file (not sure where it is on windows).

Comment: If you are sure that it is running you can try connecting directly to it by running `telnet localhost 5672` in a cmd terminal. If it connects that's good, and you can verify that it's the rabbit-server by typing some junk and hitting return a few times. The server should respond with a lline starting with `AMQP...`. If you can't connect to it with telnet then you need to investigate why - probably you have port 5672 blocked in your firewall settings.

Comment: do i need to change any settings. after downloading the above mentioned packages i just double click the package they start installation. i had set only those two environment variable only. do i need to set anything else.

Comment: i had used netstat -an to see all the ports but it doesnt have 5672 port listed in it.

Comment: Which 2 environment variables did you set? According to the doco you need to reinstall the server if you change environment variables. Have you verified that the server is running using any of the methods that I suggested? The original answer that I provided (format of the ` host` parameter) is correct. You should accept it. The rest of this discussion relates to sys admin and strictly speaking does not belong in SO.

Comment: i had set RABBITMQ_SERVER and RABBITMQ_BASE. i had mentioned these variables under my question. in task manager under services category i am able to see RabbitMQ running. and i am not able to find server logs in rabbitMq installation folder or in %APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\ . And using telnet in cmd it say telnet is not recognised.

Comment: Can u help me regarding this

Comment: Those environment variables have no affect on host:port. From what you have said the server should be running on the default port 5672 and listening on all interfaces, so connecting to localhost port 5672 should be correct. Have you read https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html in particular the sections on port access and logging? You might want to ask for help on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) or on http://serverfault.com